# Load gallery at with particuler image position

Tags: android

I have a list of images in grid view.I want to display a gallery of all this on click event of any image in grid view.I wanted to display selected image in gallery first when its load.I have position of all this images.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I want to display particular image display first when gallery load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code for your gallery widget:

`Gallery.setSelection(position);`